# Error JSONException: No Value For

Tags: java, android

i want show data with jsonarray

my code activity

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_gadai", id_gadai));          
        // getting JSON string from URL
        String json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_GADAI_DETAIL, "GET",
                params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Data Gadai Detail: ", json);

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            if(jObj != null){
                nama_brg = jObj.getString(TAG_NAMA_BRG);
                taksiran = jObj.getString(TAG_TAKSIRAN);
                pinjaman = jObj.getString(TAG_PINJAMAN);
            }          

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

my jsonarray from database
`{"data_gadai_detail":[{"id_gadai":"3","nama_brg":"BERLIAN L FINE GOLD
BERSERTIFIKAT NO.SERI JS 006 DTM 24K BRT 10
GRAM","pinjaman":"2000000","taksiran":"4000000","tgl_bts_tebus":"05-May-2013","tgl_bts_lelang":"09-May-2013"}]}`

show error :
Error JSONException: No Value For nama_brg

Need help for my problem. thks

Comment: What is the value of constant `TAG_NAMA_BRG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a JSONArray named "data_gadai_detail" as root, then you need to get the first JSONObject and then you can get the JSONStrings

try this:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);
if(jObj != null){
    nama_brg = jObj.getJSONArray("data_gadai_detail").getJSONObject(0).getString(TAG_NAMA_BRG);
    taksiran = jObj.getJSONArray("data_gadai_detail").getJSONObject(0).getString(TAG_TAKSIRAN);
    pinjaman = jObj.getJSONArray("data_gadai_detail").getJSONObject(0).getString(TAG_PINJAMAN);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON represents an object with one single field: `data_gadai_detail`:

```
{"data_gadai_detail": ...}
```

The value of this field is an array with a single element:

```
{"data_gadai_detail": [...]}
```

This single element is an object with several fields, one of them being `nama_brg`.

So your code should first get the field `data_gadai_detail` as an array, take the first element of this array as another JSON object, and finally get the String `nama_brg` in this object.

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);

    JSONArray arr = jObj.getJSONArray("data_gadai_detail");

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject c = arr.getJSONObject(i);
        nama_brg = c.getString(TAG_NAMA_BRG);
        taksiran = c.getString(TAG_TAKSIRAN);
        pinjaman = c.getString(TAG_PINJAMAN);
    }
```